# JSON file clarification

Tags: mysql, json, e-commerce

I am making a simple mock eCommerce website, that does not need to connect to a database exactly. I heard that I could use JSON files in order to create a simple small file that would almost work like a database, on a small scale. It would have several fields and an unique id field in order to differentiate the inventory. This is due in a few weeks. It does not have to have full functionality, just look up products, and the shopping cart feature. Would it be easier to use phpmyadmin, or go ahead and try to use JSON.

I would only be pulling information from the files and displaying them on a page. As products and product information as such. I wouldn't be changing them, deleting them, or adding any more after the initial creation.

We don't expect more than one person to load the website at a time either.

I am thinking there will be 80 different products or so. Probably a lot less.

> productId productType price productDescription

The above would be the fields each product will hold, just a simple id, what type of product it is, a description and a price.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON array like this which holds product information:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": -78.75,
            "longitude": 20.4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "A blue mouse",
        "price": 25.50,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 3.1,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": 54.4,
            "longitude": -32.7
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Tags would be something that they can search for, correct?

Comment: right so that you can have multiple products tagged to meaningful categories

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are loading information. Is JSON a feasible format?

If you're using REST calls, you'll probably be calling URLs such as /inventory or /cart to retrieve the inventory or the shopping cart's contents. These calls will activate routines to connect to a database and retrieve information, format the result as JSON and send it along.

For mocking up the operation of the website, you can store the inventory and cart URLs in a configuration variable. When demoing, the inventory URL will be something like /mockup/inventory.json and it will contain the same information format the real URL is expected to supply. At that point, the client side code will react exactly as if the database was online.

Except that of course the contents of both inventory and shopping cart will not change (so you can't add anything to the shopping cart, nor remove it).

Or you can maybe configure the webserver to reroute URLs such as /product/12345/info to /mockup/sample-product.json, and so on. In Apache this allows you to switch between real and fake DB by simply switching a .htaccess file.

Comment: So while using json files, we cannot enable the shopping cart feature?